# Exim - looking up account in both saslauthd and passwd file

Tags: exim, smtp-auth

I have a working Exim4 setup on Debian Bullseye, authentication uses plaintext/saslauthd.
I would like to add a few "service account" emails on the localhost, and I believ ethe easiest way forward is to add those accounts to the passwd-file, but am struggling to configure the authenticator.

/etc/exim4/passwd

```
auth:{md5}$1$RXXXXXgJ$JXQLAxVcniEpMr04CRpar/ # generated with 'mkpasswd -5 -s'
```

/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template

```
begin authenticators
plain_server:
 driver = plaintext
 public_name = PLAIN_LOCAL
 server_condition = "${if crypteq{$auth3}{${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$auth2}lsearch{CONFDIR/passwd}{$value}{*:*}}}}}{1}{0}}"
 server_set_id = $auth2
 server_prompts = :
 .ifndef AUTH_SERVER_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
   server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{}{*}}
 .endif
```

(this is not working, as I already have a PLAIN authenticator, shown below)

```
plain_saslauthd_server:
 driver = plaintext
 public_name = PLAIN
 server_condition = ${if saslauthd{{$auth2}{$auth3}}{1}{0}}
 server_set_id = $auth2
 server_prompts = :
 .ifndef AUTH_SERVER_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
   server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{}{*}}
 .endif
```

Here, I think I should add a condition to the server_condition:

```
server_condition = ${if eq {$sender_host_address}{127.0.0.1}
                      {${if crypteq{$auth3}{${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$auth2}lsearch{CONFDIR/passwd}{$value}{*:*}}}}}{1}{0}}}
                      {${if saslauthd{{$auth2}{$auth3}}{1}{0}}}
                   }
```

But update-exim4.conf --check fails with error "option setting expected" on line 2 of the server_condition... What am I doing wrong?